# About the safe use of catch(...) in C++

Tags: c++, exception, catch-all

I was arguing with a colleague about the dangers of using `catch(...)`

He was pointing me a possible use, *rigorously implying* that any `catch(...)` is followed by a trace/log: so as to help determining the origins of some unmanaged exceptions.

I am personnally rather skeptical about that. Do you know about any clear safe use of `catch(...)`

**EDIT**: For those interessested in the debate, my colleague has just pointed me to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123436/is-catch-throw-a-bad-practice) on Programmers site.

Comment: You don't need try/catch to print backtrace.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean regarding the question ?

Comment: What is a "trace/log" in this context? (as far as I know `catch(...)` doesn't launch anything).

Comment: By "launches" I think he meant "is followed by".

Comment: not clear, but he said "trace/log" ... "origins of some unmanaged exceptions". for me it's a backtrace, or i miss something ?

Comment: I meant "followed by" ( I edited to put that). This is why I used the words **"rigorously implying"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are often overused. Almost always this overuse is accompanied by catch-all statements. This is usually a sign of a bad use and understanding of exceptions. I never recommend it. Sadly, at some (bad) place I worked in, other people enforced this policy.

Comment: Try writing the copy constructor of `std::vector` correctly without a generic `catch` block...

Comment: @KerrekSB I was talking about a widespread, arbitrary use of catch-all blocks.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I understand you, this is the same very reason why I ask this question here :-)

Comment: +1 @KerrekSB: Even that is possible, just write a helper class to manage the resources.

Comment: @ipc: Non-obligatorily: Would you care to demonstrate how you'd do that in an example (e.g. on ideone)? I'm curious.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry, I've not that much time, but I wrote a [`dup`](http://ideone.com/zIE58c) with `malloc` and `free`. This should be pretty much the same idea as vector's copy constructor.

Comment: @ipc: Oh, sorry, I got confused! Thanks, reading it now. [Edit:] Yeah, that looks about right. And it's much clearer than the ugly `try` - `throw`, too :-)

Answer (score 5):

The clearest interesting safe use of `catch(...)` that I'm aware of is to offload code for handling various exceptions to a shared function:

```
void handle_error() {
    try {
        throw;
    } catch (TiresomelyPedanticException &) {
        # lah lah I don't care
        return;
    } catch (InterestingException &) {
        log_something();
        throw;
    }
    // etc. This catch chain may *or may not* need a catch(...)
    // of its own, it depends whether part of its job is to
    // deal with the "miscellaneous" case.
}
```

You use the function like this:

```
try {
    blah();
} catch(...) {
    handle_error();
}
```

... somewhere else ...

```
try {
    something_that_throws_the_same_exceptions_as_blah();
} catch (...) {
    handle_error();
}
```

The pattern above might turn out to be a bit of a C++03-ism, though. In C++11 it's so easy to write a capturing lambda, that the following might be more useful to callers, and there's no `catch(...)` in the pattern:

```
template <typename Func>
auto do_and_handle_error(Func f) -> decltype(f()) {
    try {
        return f();
    } // catch chain goes here
}
```

Use it like:

```
do_and_handle_error(blah);
```

or as would actually turn out to be necessary when `blah` takes arguments:

```
do_and_handle_error([&](void) { return blah(arg1,arg2); });
```

---

A boring use of `catch(...)` is to guarantee that the stack will be unwound before program termination:

```
int my_main() {
    RAIIClass some_object_i_want_to_get_destroyed_no_matter_what;
    some_code_that_might_throw();
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    try {
        return my_main();
    } catch (...) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Without the catch, the standard leaves it either unspecified or implementation-defined whether or not `some_object` is destroyed if the code throws.

Comment: Comedy comment: `int main() { try` -- why not `int main() try {`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: pure prejudice on my part against an oppressed and marginalized minority language feature ;-)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I'm a bit lost with your `try {throw;}` -- is that legit? I mean, the exception is never active inside the original `catch` block, and isn't it instant termination to call `throw;` without an active exception?

Comment: @KerrekSB: when `handle_error()` is called from inside a catch block, there's a throwable exception in play (I honestly can't remember at the moment whether "active" is the correct word for that, I have a sneaking feeling an "active exception" is one that has been thrown but not yet caught). The existence or not of an exception that can be thrown with an empty `throw;` statement is dynamically scoped, not lexically scoped. In effect it is a property of the current call stack, not of the block in which the code appears.

Answer (score 3):

The following is always safe:

```
try
{
    some_local_stuff();
}
catch (...)
{
    clean_up_local_stuff();
    throw;
}
```

In other words, the catch-all `catch` block should only be used in conjunction with either rethrowing the exact same exception or storing exception pointer to transport the exception.

Catch blocks that make an exception go away entirely should be specific about the type of exception they handle.

Comment: Of course, the cleaning up should (nearly always) be done by destructors, but that's another story.

Comment: ... or unsafe code in destructors.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Errr.. what if you're writing the copy constructor of a `vector`?!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, I should have been a bit less absolute. I've added a "nearly always" to appease the pedants.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I got that :-) My point is that in order to have all the wonderful rule-of-zero magic, *someone* has to write the component classes, and *that's* where the code I presented comes in as typical.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think that all such cases *can* be rewritten to have a class whose role is to hold on to the local stuff, and that has a `release()` function so that if everything succeeds, the stuff can be taken out of that class and put where it needs to go. Whether you want to write it like that is another matter, I guess it's down to how far you want to take RAII as the One True Way To Clean Stuff Up In The Event Of An Exception.